# Installing AUCTeX on Windows from package-install

Tags: miktex, installing, windows, emacs, auctex

I have Emacs 24 and MikTeX on Windows 7 professional and I have recently installed AUCTeX 11.86 from package-install.

The installation seems to have completed successfully, I even succeeded at compiling a latex sample file, but I can use AUCTeX only in the emacs instance where I issued the installation command, where it gets loaded by package-install. I can't do the same with a new emacs instance.

Nothing seems to have been written in my .emacs file upon installation and I can't find the `auctex.el` file, which the AUCTeX installations instructions report to be found inside the auctex directory `(.emacs.d/elpa/auctex)`, to load AUCTeX at initialization time.

Any idea on how I can solve the issue?

Comment: Please consider editing your profile name so that you don't have to sign with it since [it will automatically appear in the lower right corner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) of your post.

Comment: You should add the lines `(load "auctex.e" nil t t)` and `(load "preview-latex.el" nil t t)` in your .emacs (I think in windows the initialization has another name)

Comment: @PeterBreitfeld: thanks, but that's the problem: I can't find /auctex.el/ anywhere on my disk. 
Other instruction on installing auctex on Windows don't refer to platform-specific scripts to be called in place of /auctex.el/.

Comment: try looking in /../site-lisp/site-start/auctex.el. I have (require 'tex-site) in my .emacs. Hope it helps!

Comment: @Dualinity: no site-lisp directory. I can't find auctex.el anywhere on my disk.
And (require 'tex-site) does nothing

Comment: site-lisp directory should be in the folder where you installed emacs (when you install emacs, it's there)

Comment: I have my emacs addons under ~/.emacs.d/, where ~ points to the 'AppData/Roaming/' directory.
Everything works fine from there, including other elpa packages, except auctex.

Comment: When installing AUCTeX from ELPA, you *must not* add `(load "auctex.el" nil t t)` and `(load "preview-latex.el" nil t t)` to your init file.

Comment: Did you solve the problem? I have the same: AUCTeX is usable after installing it from ELPA. After a restart of EMACS (or in a new instance) it doesn't load anymore when opening a TeX file.

Comment: @feklee I think a new question would be best: this one got closed as we had no feedback from the questionner on whether the suggestions work. So if you are keen to solve it, ask a new question and be ready to try things out!

Comment: @JosephWright So you recommend that I copy and paste this question?

Comment: I just flagged the question, asking for reopening. Reason is that I have found a solution that works for me, and that I would like to add as an answer.